# cannot display multiple markers in google maps v3 from traceroute result

Tags: php, google-maps-api-3, traceroute

i'm newbie in php mysql and google maps v3. i have a problems in google maps v3. i made traceroute web based and map the traceroute's result in the google maps v3 for my final project of my college education. i have try so many tutorials but it didn't work. i also have tried the tutorials in this forum but nothing worked. so my problem is i cannot display multiple markers that i got the location data from database. maybe because i'm newbie and do not know how to do. i also confuse with the looping to show the markers. so here is the code

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ (E_NOTICE));
ini_set('max_execution_time', 360);
$enable_log_user = FALSE;

global $ip, $host_name,  $host_ip;

$host  = @$_POST['host']; 
$trace = @$_POST['trace'];
$self  = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

include("phpsqlajax_dbinfo.php");
$connection = mysql_connect ('127.0.0.1', $username, $password);
if (!$connection) {  die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());} 

$db_selected = mysql_select_db($database, $connection);
if (!$db_selected) {
  die ('Can\'t use db : ' . mysql_error());
} 

?>
<!DOCTYPE html >
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <title>PHP/MySQL & Google Maps Example</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[

 </script>
  </head>
<body onload="initialize()">
var pinImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage ("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_xpin_letter_withshadow&chld=pin_star|%E2%80%A2|CC3300|000000|FF9900",
        new google.maps.Size (70, 83),
        new google.maps.Point (0,0),
        new google.maps.Point (10,34));
    var pinShadow = new google.maps.MarkerImage ("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_shadow",
        new google.maps.Size (89, 85),
        new google.maps.Point (0, 0),
        new google.maps.point (12, 35));

    var map;
    function initialize() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(41.258531,-96.012599);
    var myOptions = {
    zoom: 2,
    center: myLatlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    <!-- var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow; -->
    } 
    </script>
    <form name="tools" action="<?php $self ?>" method="post">
    <p><font size="2">Your IP is <?php $ip ?> </font></p>
    <input type="text" name="host" value=""></input>
    <input type="submit" name="trace" value="Traceroute!"></input>
    </form>
    <?php
    if ($_POST['submit']) 
{
    if (($host == 'Enter Host or IP') || ($host == "")) {
        echo '<br><br>You must enter a valid Host or IP address.';
        exit; } 

    if(eregi("^[a-z]",  $host))
    {
        $host_name = $host;
        $host_ip = gethostbyname($host);
    }
    else
    {
        $host_name = gethostbyaddr($host);
        $host_ip = $host;
    } 
}


    $host= preg_replace ("[-a-z0-9!#$%&\'*+/=?^_`{|}~]","",$host);
    $command = "tracert $host";
    $fp = shell_exec("$command 2>&1");
    $output .= (htmlentities(trim($fp)));
    echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
    echo '<br/>';

    $array = array($output);
    $space_separated = implode(" ", $array);

    function explodeRows($data) {
      $rowsArr = explode("\n", $data);
      return $rowsArr;
    }
    function explodeTabs($singleLine) {
      $parsed = preg_split('/ +/', $singleLine);
      return $parsed;
    }
    $data     = $space_separated;
    $rowsArr  = explodeRows($data);

    for($a=3;$a<count($rowsArr)-2;$a++) 
    {
        $lineDetails[$a] = explodeTabs($rowsArr[$a]);

        if (empty($lineDetails[$a][9]))
        {
            $ipList[] = $lineDetails[$a][8];
        }
        else
        {
            $ipList[] = substr($lineDetails[$a][9], 1, -1);
        }
    }

    for ($b=0; $b<count($ipList); $b++)
    {
        if ($ipList[$b] != "")
        {
            $arrLine[]=$ipList[$b];
        }
    }

function ip_address_to_number($IPaddress)
{
    if ($IPaddress == "") {
        return 0;
    } else {
        $ips = explode (".", "$IPaddress");
        return ($ips[3] + $ips[2] * 256 + $ips[1] * 256 * 256 + $ips[0] * 256 * 256 * 256);
    }
}
for($c=0; $c<count($arrLine); $c++) {
$integer[] = ip_address_to_number($arrLine[$c]);
}
    foreach ($integer as $lokasi) {
    $query = "SELECT cl.locId, cl.country as country, cl.region as region, cl.city as city, cl.postalCode as postalCode, cl.latitude as latitude, cl.longitude as longitude, cl.metroCode as metroCode, cl.areaCode as areaCode
    FROM (SELECT locId as idcihuy FROM cityblocks WHERE $lokasi BETWEEN startIpNum AND endIpNum) cb, citylocation cl WHERE cb.idcihuy = cl.locId";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    while ($location = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $country[] = $location['country'];
    $region[] = $location['region'];
    $city[] = $location['city'];
    $postalCode[] = $location['postalCode'];
    $latitude[] = $location['latitude'];
    $longitude[] = $location['longitude'];
    $metroCode[] = $location['metroCode'];
    $areaCode[] = $location['areaCode'];
    }
    }
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     var point = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $latitude ?>, <?php echo $longitude; ?>);
     var icon = pinImage;
     var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: point,
        icon: pinImage,
        shadow: pinShadow
        });
    </script>
<div id="map_canvas" style="width: 900px; height: 500px"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

okay, here is my html source code, yes there's something wrong it seems :

```
<!DOCTYPE html >

  <head>

    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />

    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>

    <title>PHP/MySQL & Google Maps Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    //<![CDATA[

    var pinImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage ("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_xpin_letter_withshadow&chld=pin_star|%E2%80%A2|CC3300|000000|FF9900",

        new google.maps.Size (70, 83),

        new google.maps.Point (0,0),

        new google.maps.Point (10,34));

    var pinShadow = new google.maps.MarkerImage ("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_shadow",

        new google.maps.Size (89, 85),

        new google.maps.Point (0, 0),

        new google.maps.point (12, 35));



    var map;

    function initialize() {

    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(41.258531,-96.012599);

    var myOptions = {

    zoom: 2,

    center: myLatlng,

    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP

    }

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

    <!-- var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow; -->

    } 

    </script>

  </head>

<body onload="initialize()">

<form name="tools" action="" method="post">

    <p><font size="2">Your IP is  </font></p>

    <input type="text" name="host" value=""></input>

    <input type="submit" name="trace" value="Traceroute!"></input>

    </form>

    <pre>Tracing route to detik.com [203.190.242.69]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  2   199 ms   177 ms   179 ms  192.168.36.11 
  3   385 ms   359 ms   299 ms  192.168.39.8 
  4  2005 ms  1400 ms  1536 ms  192.168.39.8 
  5  1857 ms  1277 ms  1874 ms  192.168.36.11 
  6  2359 ms  3401 ms     *     192.168.39.196 
  7  2477 ms  2641 ms     *     114.127.254.78 
  8  2230 ms  1203 ms  1570 ms  114.127.254.2 
  9  1595 ms  1642 ms  3005 ms  giga-0-0.openixp.net [218.100.27.129] 
 10     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 11     *     2517 ms  3294 ms  203.190.244.6 
 12  1632 ms  2961 ms  1297 ms  203.190.242.69 

Trace complete.</pre><br/>

    <script type="text/javascript">

     var point = new google.maps.LatLng(-5.0000, 120.0000);

     var icon = pinImage;

     var marker = new google.maps.Marker({

        map: map,

        position: point,

        icon: pinImage,

        shadow: pinShadow

        });

    </script>

<div id="map_canvas" style="width: 900px; height: 500px"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

well, i'm really sorry if you guys read my code. it looks mess. because i don't know how to display the code well. the most important thing i want to be helped is in the maps. for how to show all the markers. especially the looping. the google maps doesn't show the markers. it only display the maps. so for all the masters who read this question. i just need your help as soon as possible. i'm really sorry if my english was bad and my mistake to you guys. thanks in advance.

Comment: I only know little php, doesn't `echo $latitude` need a semicolon `;` ? If you can post the output HTML (the page showing in your browser) maybe I can help more.

Comment: @Lilina okay maybe i will show you the output. but  really really sorry i don't know how to attach an image of the output. i will give you the screenshot but via my tumblr. would you mind to see my tumblr?? here's the link chumyeeallalone.tumblr.com in the first posting or this link to see the image clearly http://24.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m563qe4H0U1qgl2jgo1_1280.jpg . very big thanks if you could help me. i really need the help to fix this problem :'(

Comment: I mean the HTML source code, sorry for not being clear.

Comment: @Lilina,i'm sorry i don't understand with the html source code. i just have one file. the file is like i posted in my question. i am really sorry. so actually i use that code and the browser just show like the image i give you before when i run it :)

Comment: OK, what I mean is in your browser, right-click somewhere on the page, and there's an option "View source" or "view page source", it'll be a bunch of text, that looks a lot like what you posted in your question but all the PHP will have become text. This is what I am interested in.

Comment: oke i got it. but how can i give you the html source code. i can't post in this comment because of this limited character. do i have to give you the source code by answering my own answer??

Comment: You can edit your question or use a site like pastebin.com

Comment: @Lilina, check out my question. i have added my html source code. big thanks Lilina :). i will wait for your answer. sorry for my annoying question ... :D

Comment: I think the simplest thing to do is to move all of the google maps code below "Trace complete." My reasoning was that the page was trying to add the marker before the map finished loading. See how I moved the google maps code http://pastebin.com/Un8K8KMF

Comment: @lilina, thanks. it was helpful. and i have moved the google maps code like what you did. it showed the marker. but it just only one marker. i need some markers from output traceroute shows in google maps i have moved and modify the code. so here is my php code http://pastebin.com/aVP8itrw and this is my html code http://pastebin.com/V5KyL37u. is there any something wrong with the looping to show many markers?? sorry lilina, i annoying you anymore. big thanks in advance :)

Comment: I don't understand everything of what you did, I would suggest, when looping through the SQL results for latitude and longitude, save them as an array, then when you reach the google maps section get these numbers back from the array (instead of the single `echo latitude`)

Comment: sorry lilina, can you explain it clearer about the array?? while i try to understand about array. yes this is that maybe one of my mistake in this source code and my weakness in array and looping. i'll try to keep learning by the way. thanks :)

Comment: I'm thinking how I would place the markers in Javascript, since I don't know much PHP. I would use push to add these latitudes and longitudes in arrays, it looks like array_push in php does something like it. http://roseindia.net/tutorial/php/phpbasics/PHP-Array-Push.html  Sorry I'm not much help with php :(

Comment: okay @Lilina, thanks for the help. i'm sorry of my mistake and annoying things of me to you. actually it helps. for the less, i will try to learn, especially about the markers. really big thanks for you lilina.

Comment: You were not being annoying, it's just hard for me to help also because I cannot test the code easily. Hope your project turns out well :)